# Checkboxes and forms and php mail

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a form that has a php script that it posts to.
In the form I have added a number of multi check boxes that are separated by 2 different IDs ("info" and "question")

```
<form action='../php/email.php' id='form' name='form'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Name' type='text'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='E-mail' type='text'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='phone' name='phone' placeholder='Phone' type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <textarea class='form-control' id='message' name='message' placeholder='Message'></textarea>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 service'><strong>Would you like more information about:</strong>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Assessment Tools" id="info" name="Assessment Tools" />
            <label for="Assessment Tools"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Assessment Tools 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Supervisory and Management Development" id="info" name="Supervisory and Management Development" />
            <label for="Supervisory and Management Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Supervisory and Management Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Employee Training and Development" id="info" name="Employee Training and Development" />
            <label for="Employee Training and Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Employee Training and Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="ELearning" id="info" name="ELearning" />
            <label for="E-Learning"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            E-Learning
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Policies and Procedures" id="info" name="Policies and Procedures" />
            <label for="Policies and Procedures"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Policies and Procedures
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Employee Surveys" id="info" name="Employee Surveys" />
            <label for="Employee Surveys"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Employee Surveys
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Team Building" id="info" name="Team Building" />
            <label for="Team Building"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Team Building
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Career Development" id="info" name="Career Development" />
            <label for="Career Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Career Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Succession Managemen" id="info" name="Succession Managemen" />
            <label for="Succession Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Succession Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Recruitment and Selection" id="info" name="Recruitment and Selection" />
            <label for="Recruitment and Selection"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Recruitment and Selection
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Outsourced Services" id="info" name="Outsourced Services" />
            <label for="Outsourced Services"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Outsourced Services
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Leadership Coaching" id="info" name="Leadership Coaching" />
            <label for="Leadership Coaching"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Leadership Coaching
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Strategy Development" id="info" name="Strategy Development" />
            <label for="Strategy Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Strategy Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Performance Management" id="info" name="Performance Management" />
            <label for="Performance Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Performance Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Change Management" id="info" name="Change Management" />
            <label for="Change Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Change Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Outplacement Services" id="info" name="Outplacement Services" />
            <label for=" Outplacement Services"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Outplacement Services
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5 service'>
        <strong>Do you have a question about:</strong>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Selection and Hiring for Fit" id="question" name="Selection and Hiring for Fit" />
            <label for="Selection and Hiring for Fit"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Selection and Hiring for "Fit" 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Managing Talent" id="question" name="Managing Talent" />
            <label for="Managing Talent"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Managing Talent 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Developing Leadership" id="question" name="Developing Leadership" />
            <label for="Developing Leadership"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Developing Leadership
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Improving Employee Productivity" id="question" name="Improving Employee Productivity" />
            <label for="Improving Employee Productivity"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Improving Employee Productivity
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Engaging the Workforce" id="question" name="Engaging the Workforce" />
            <label for="Engaging the Workforce"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Engaging the Workforce
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Increasing Sales Effectiveness" id="question" name="Increasing Sales Effectiveness" />
            <label for="Increasing Sales Effectiveness"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Increasing Sales Effectiveness
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Improving Customer Service" id="question" name="Improving Customer Service" />
            <label for="Improving Customer Service"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Improving Customer Service
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Reducing Risk - HR Compliance" id="question" name="Reducing Risk - HR Compliance" />
            <label for="Reducing Risk - HR Compliance"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Reducing Risk - HR Compliance
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class='form-control' id='send' type='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

And the PHP Form looks like this:

```
<?php
$subject = 'MTMPS Website Form Submission';
$to      = 'mike@iwillfillinlater.com';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . ' <br/>' .
           'E-mail: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Phone: ' . $_REQUEST['phone'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Message: ' .$_REQUEST['message'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Requesting Information On: ' . $_REQUEST['info'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Have a Question About: ' . $_REQUEST['question'] . ' <br/>';
if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Your Message has been sent, Thank you!';
} else {
    echo 'Oops there was a problem and your message was not sent';
}
?>
```

I am at a loss for how to properly format the last 2 requests. I would love to get some help on this as Im sure it will not work in its current state. Especially if it sends back multiple answers for each request.

Comment: Format, or code?  They're two different things; one is a matter of preference, the other is defined logic.

Comment: There are numerous things wrong with your code. You should start by [enabling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display#answer-21429652). Also, why are you showing us the entire form when you only use a handful of what is in it?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and refactored your code. Should work now as far as the form values (did not test the mail send functionality).
Notice that I am using the name fields only, it is bad practice to use multiple DOM elements with the same id.

The 'trick' is that when using multiple checkboxes with the same name and square brackets, PHP receives it as an array. i.e you can use multiple checkboxes with different value but same name:

`<input type="checkbox" value="value1" name="my_checkbox[]">`

`<input type="checkbox" value="value2" name="my_checkbox[]">`

Your HTML markup should be:

```
<form action='../php/email.php' id='form' name='form'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Name' type='text'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='E-mail' type='text'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <input class='form-control' id='phone' name='phone' placeholder='Phone' type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <textarea class='form-control' id='message' name='message' placeholder='Message'></textarea>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 service'><strong>Would you like more information about:</strong>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Assessment Tools" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Assessment Tools"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Assessment Tools 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Supervisory and Management Development"name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Supervisory and Management Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Supervisory and Management Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Employee Training and Development" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Employee Training and Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Employee Training and Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="ELearning" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="E-Learning"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            E-Learning
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Policies and Procedures" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Policies and Procedures"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Policies and Procedures
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Employee Surveys" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Employee Surveys"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Employee Surveys
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Team Building" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Team Building"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Team Building
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Career Development" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Career Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Career Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Succession Managemen" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Succession Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Succession Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Recruitment and Selection" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Recruitment and Selection"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Recruitment and Selection
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Outsourced Services" name="more_info[]"/>
            <label for="Outsourced Services"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Outsourced Services
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Leadership Coaching" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Leadership Coaching"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Leadership Coaching
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Strategy Development" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Strategy Development"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Strategy Development
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Performance Management" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for="Performance Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Performance Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Change Management" name="more_info[]"/>
            <label for="Change Management"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Change Management
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Outplacement Services" name="more_info[]" />
            <label for=" Outplacement Services"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Outplacement Services
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5 service'>
        <strong>Do you have a question about:</strong>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Selection and Hiring for Fit" name="questions[]"/>
            <label for="Selection and Hiring for Fit"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Selection and Hiring for "Fit" 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Managing Talent" id="question" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Managing Talent"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Managing Talent 
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Developing Leadership" name="questions[]"/>
            <label for="Developing Leadership"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Developing Leadership
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Improving Employee Productivity" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Improving Employee Productivity"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Improving Employee Productivity
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Engaging the Workforce" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Engaging the Workforce"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Engaging the Workforce
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Increasing Sales Effectiveness" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Increasing Sales Effectiveness"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Increasing Sales Effectiveness
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Improving Customer Service" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Improving Customer Service"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Improving Customer Service
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Reducing Risk - HR Compliance" name="questions[]" />
            <label for="Reducing Risk - HR Compliance"></label>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>
            Reducing Risk - HR Compliance
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class='form-control' id='send' type='submit' value='Send'>
```

And your PHP script should be:

```
<?php

$more_info = isset( $_REQUEST['more_info']) ? implode(', ', $_REQUEST['more_info']) : 'no info boxes selected';
$questions = isset($_REQUEST['questions']) ? implode(', ', $_REQUEST['questions']) : 'no questions selected';

$subject = 'MTMPS Website Form Submission';
$to      = 'mike@iwillfillinlater.com';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . ' <br/>' .
           'E-mail: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Phone: ' . $_REQUEST['phone'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Message: ' .$_REQUEST['message'] . ' <br/>' .
           'Requesting Information On: ' . $more_info . ' <br/>' .
           'Have a Question About: ' . $questions . ' <br/>';
if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Your Message has been sent, Thank you!';
} else {
    echo 'Oops there was a problem and your message was not sent';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!